# SQL Server: group by and DATEADD confusion

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, dateadd

I have a problem in my `SELECT` query with `GROUP BY` and `DATEADD`, and it goes like this: (*see sample sql code below*)

```
SELECT 
    'USER1' AS [user_id],
    DATEADD(hh,-15,log_date) AS [LogDate],
    MIN(DATEADD(hh,-15,login_time)) AS [Login],
    MAX(DATEADD(hh,-15,logout_time)) AS [Logout],
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(DATEADD(hh,-15,login_time)),
    MAX(DATEADD(hh,-15,logout_time)))/60.0  AS [TotalHrs]
FROM 
    tblDTR
WHERE 
    user_id = 'USER1' 
    AND log_date BETWEEN CAST('02/07/2014' AS datetime) 
                     AND CAST('02/28/2014' AS datetime)
GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    DATEADD(hh, -15, log_date)
ORDER BY 
    LogDate ASC
```

and this is the result:

[image]

What I want to do is the `LogDate` column must display the **REAL DATE&TIME** (meaning, column must not subtracted to **-15**), and also as you can see on the result table above on `LogDate` column, though I used `GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, -15, log_date)` it didn't works at all. Did I missed some function on my SQL code?

Here's my new SQL code to display the `LogDate` without **subtracted to 15**:

```
SELECT 
    'USER1' AS [user_id],
    CONVERT(varchar,log_date,101) AS [LogDate], <-- I changed here but it didn't work, it give me error.
    MIN(DATEADD(hh, -15, login_time)) AS [Login],
    MAX(DATEADD(hh, -15, logout_time)) AS [Logout],
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(DATEADD(hh, -15, login_time)),
    MAX(DATEADD(hh, -15, logout_time)))/60.0  AS [TotalHrs]
FROM 
    tblDTR
WHERE 
    user_id = 'USER1' 
    AND log_date BETWEEN CAST('02/07/2014' AS datetime) 
                     AND CAST('02/28/2014' AS datetime)
GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    DATEADD(hh, -15, log_date)
ORDER BY 
    LogDate ASC
```

Error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 'tblDTR.log_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any alternative and suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
BTW, I'm using SQL Server 2012

**OUTPUT MUST BE:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id |   LogDate  |       Login      |      LogOut      | TotalHrs |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  USER1  | 02/07/2014 | 2014-02-07 08:12 | 2014-02-07 19:30 |   11.28  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You say the `group by` is not working.. It is working, but I suspect you want it to group the days together? You'll have to convert the `log_date` to a `DATE` datatype first, because it's a `DATETIME` now, it's grouping by every individual datetime in that column.    And why are you actually substracting 15 hours?

Comment: Where does the `03/08/2014` come from in `LogDate`? How do you determine that?

Comment: **03/08/2014** is the REAL DATE of LOGDATE(not yet subtracted to 15) but I want to `GROUP BY` LOGDATE Column by the time it is subtracted to 15

Comment: You have a `where` clause with `log_date BETWEEN CAST('02/07/2014' AS datetime) AND CAST('02/28/2014' AS datetime)`, so `03/08/2014` will never be a result of this.

Comment: I'm sorry. that must be **02/07/2014**. I already update the post above.

Comment: @NickyvV: Thank you so much. I already got it! I know it's weird.. but you helped me..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap your select with another one, adding back the 15 hours:

```
SELECT [user_id],
    DATEADD(hh, 15 ,LogDate) AS [LogDate],
    [Login],
    [Logout],
    [TotalHrs]
FROM (
    SELECT 
    'USER1' AS [user_id],
    DATEADD(hh,-15,log_date) AS [LogDate],
    MIN(DATEADD(hh,-15,login_time)) AS [Login],
    MAX(DATEADD(hh,-15,logout_time)) AS [Logout],
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(DATEADD(hh,-15,login_time)),
                    MAX(DATEADD(hh,-15,logout_time)))/60.0  AS [TotalHrs]
    FROM tblDTR
    WHERE user_id = 'USER1' 
        AND log_date
            BETWEEN CAST('02/07/2014' AS datetime) 
                AND CAST('02/28/2014' AS datetime)
    GROUP BY 
        user_id,
        DATEADD(hh,-15,log_date)
) InnerQueryAlias
    ORDER BY LogDate ASC
```

Comment: I'm getting error on the first SELECTed Columns. Please see updated post above for desired output.

Comment: @Waelhi See my edited answer. I've added an alias to the inner query that solved the problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ad95/3

Answer (score 0):

In GROUP BY clause of your query, replace

```
DATEADD(hh,-15,log_date)
```

with

```
tblDTR.log_date
```

Comment: @Waelhi: The convert statement for **[LogDate]** that you are using in your query will give you the desired date format (i.e.  02/08/2014 ). But just make sure that you are adding log_date column in your **GROUP BY** clause to get rid of the error.